Send Email using Yahoo and C#
Hello I'm trying to generate send a email for yahoo using Mailkit.
Here's the code below:
var message = new MimeMessage();
message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("", "yahooemail@yahoo.com"));
message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("", "testemail@yopmail.com"));
message.Subject = "Test";

var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder
{
    HtmlBody = emailBody
};

using (var client = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
{
    client.Connect("smtp.mail.yahoo.com", 465, true);
    await client.AuthenticateAsync("yahooemail@yahoo.com", "mypassword");

    client.Send(message);
    client.Disconnect(true);
}

However I receive the following error:
The SMTP server has unexpectedly disconnected: 5.7.0 (#AUTH005) Too many bad auth attempts.
I tried to create a app password from yahoo thinking that may be the issue but yahoo says
App passwords cannot be generated right now.
EDIT: Devlin linked a question that looked similar to mine but their solution seemed to be switching host to google's/gmail. But since I need to use a yahoo account/send email using yahoo account/smtp.

Yahoo! Mail probably requires OAuth2 authentication. There has been a big push by the major players to obsolete other forms of authentication and only support OAuth2 (Google and Microsoft are the others I know of for sure).

App password needed to send mail using your yahoo mail account. The app password can be generated from https://login.yahoo.com/myaccount/security
using the following code, you can do it.
Private Sub SendMail_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCheck.Click
        Try
            Dim mSMTPClient As String, mSMTPServerPort As Integer, mEnableSSL As Integer
            Dim email As MimeMessage = New MimeMessage()
            Dim Content As New MimeKit.BodyBuilder

            mSMTPClient = "smtp.mail.yahoo.com"
            mSMTPServerPort = 465

            email.From.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("mytest@yahoo.com"))
            email.To.Add(MailboxAddress.Parse("mytest4yahoo@gmail.com"))
            email.Subject = "Test Email from Mailing System"

            Content.TextBody = ""
            Content.HtmlBody = "hello world!!!"
            email.Body = Content.ToMessageBody

            Dim smtp As New MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient

            smtp.Connect(mSMTPClient, mSMTPServerPort, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.SslOnConnect)
            smtp.Authenticate("mytest@yahoo.com", "********")

            smtp.Send(email)
            smtp.Disconnect(True)
            MsgBox("Mail sent...", vbInformation)


        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub


I implemented in c#  on .NET Framework 4.7.
